# How to set my custom palette for Peacock in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using peacock on vscode, and i wanted to use a python-like color palette
[image]

The problem comes when i want to save it as a favorite, or, when i re-open vscode workspace, the colors are being reset to these:
[image]
it looks like the line

```
"peacock.color": "#3776ab"
```

is overriding the color palette everytime it reloads, but i haven't found a solution on the docs to fix it.